# how to control the execute flow in async in dart

Tags: dart

Now I am facing a problem, this is my Dart code:

```
Future<List<Music>?> getAvaliableFmMusics(List<Music>? recommand) async {
    final List<Music> resultMusic = List.empty(growable: true);
    if (recommand != null) {
      recommand.forEach((element) async {
        bool isLegacyMusic = await ReddwarfMusic.legacyMusic(element);
        if (!isLegacyMusic) {
          resultMusic.add(element);
        }
      });
    }
    return resultMusic;
  }
```

I get a recommand music list, the next step I check the music list is contains legacy music(user already listening for many times), then add the filtered music to a new list. Finnaly return the filtered music list to the user UI. The problem is that the legacy music will send an async http requst, the `resultMusic` always return null. What I want to do is waiting the foreach complete then return the filtered `resultMusic`,what should I do to make it work like that? is it possible to do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with `forEach` and `Futures` you should use the [Future.forEach](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-async/Future/forEach.html)

Like so:

```
await Future.forEach(yourList,(e) async {
  await asyncCall(e);
});
```